# Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=com.android.systemui

Tags: android, react-native

I have a **react-native** app that I am about to launch but I suddenly cant seem to render the apps logo in the loading splash screen.

I basically just have the following:

```
<Image
  resizeMode='cover'
  source={require('../assets/appLogos/splashScreenIcon.png')}
  style={{ width: 350, height: 350 }}
/>
```

but as soon as the image gets loaded the app crashed. I dont get a red screen or anything. When I look at `adb logcat` I see the following error:

`ResourceType:No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
Icon    : Unable to load resource 0x00000000 from pkg=com.android.systemui
Icon    : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
Icon    :   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:201)`

This only happens on android. It works fine on the iOS app.